# Assign author to comment from post edit page

Tags: comments, hooks, comment-form

How we can assign author to comment while creating this from post edit page.
When i add new comment it always automatically assign login author to this comment. But i want there a select box that user can use to select author for that comment.
Is there any hook that i can use to insert this new select box there ?

Comment: You could use a user switching plugin that allows administrators to temporarily "sign in as" another user, post the comment, then switch back to themselves.